# Select JSon objects based on criteria

Tags: javascript, json

I am working to filter a large json data set, I'd like to know how can I select json objects vertically.

Lat's take this small example, I'd like to select all the books with the name of author contains 'Evelyn'

```
data= [ 
      { "category": "reference",
        "author": "Nigel Rees",
        "title": "Sayings of the Century",
        "price":8
      },
      { "category": "fiction",
        "author": "Evelyn Waugh",
        "title": "Sword of Honour",
        "price": 8
      },
      { "category": "fiction",
        "author": "Evelyn Melville",
        "title": "Moby Dick",
        "isbn": "0-553-21311-3",
        "price": 8.99
      },
      { "category": "fiction",
        "author": "J. R. R. Tolkien",
        "title": "The Lord of the Rings",
        "isbn": "0-395-19395-8",
        "price": 22.99
      }
```

as a result I should get:

```
  { "category": "fiction",
            "author": "Evelyn Waugh",
            "title": "Sword of Honour",
            "price": 8
          },
          { "category": "fiction",
            "author": "Evelyn Melville",
            "title": "Moby Dick",
            "isbn": "0-553-21311-3",
            "price": 8.99
          },
```

Can I do it this way:

```
$.each(data,function(i,el)
{
    var newdata;
     if (data.author.contains('Evelyn')) newdata.push()
});
```

Another way :

```
 data.where( "( n, i ) => n.author.contains('Evelyn') " ) ;
```

Do you have where is the problem in the both ways, what is the fastest ways to tackle this problem as I have a huge dataset ?

Comment: FYI.  These are javascript objects, not JSON.  JSON is a text interchange format.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `Array.filter`:

```
var filtered = data.filter(function(a){return +(a.price) >= 8;}
```

Or filter on the `author` field:

```
var filtered = data.filter(function(a){return /evelyn/i.test(a.author);});
// now [filtered] contains the objects from [data] 
// where 'author' contains 'Evelyn'
// filtered.length => 2
// filtered[0].category => 'fiction'
```

[MDN filter documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) (including a shim for older browsers)

Comment: sorry! I edited the example, it should be "+.author.contains('Evelyn')". Does it work this way

Comment: It works for any field in the `data` object. See edited answer.

Comment: Might be worth mentioning that you need a polyfill for IE versions prior to IE9. Otherwise this is an excellent answer.

Comment: @BernhardHofmann: I mentioned the shim aka polyfill (follow the MDN-link, see 'Compatibility')

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this? I've used it in some of my projects and really can recommend it.
http://www.hugoware.net/projects/jlinq

Comment: Seems that you are coming from CS Linq background

Answer (score 0):

You can use `filter`:

```
data.filter(function(book) {
  return /Evelyn/.test(book.author);
});
```

Comment: I am getting boolean here . You are testing, I'd like to extract data ?

Comment: This doesn't return a boolean. It will filter all items in `data` where `book.author` contains `Evelyn`. If it doesn't work try posting a jsfiddle demo to reproduce the issue.

Answer (score 0):

`contains` operator will not work here, you'll have to use the indexOf function here.
The below code should work fine

```
data= [ 
      { "category": "reference",
        "author": "Nigel Rees",
        "title": "Sayings of the Century",
        "price":8
      },
      { "category": "fiction",
        "author": "Evelyn Waugh",
        "title": "Sword of Honour",
        "price": 8
      },
      { "category": "fiction",
        "author": "Evelyn Melville",
        "title": "Moby Dick",
        "isbn": "0-553-21311-3",
        "price": 8.99
      },
      { "category": "fiction",
        "author": "J. R. R. Tolkien",
        "title": "The Lord of the Rings",
        "isbn": "0-395-19395-8",
        "price": 22.99
      }];

data.forEach(function(args){
    if(args.author.indexOf('Evelyn') >= 0){
        console.log(args);
    }

});
```

Comment: I would like to get only element that contains 'Evelyn'. Should replace console.log(args); by newdata.push(..)

Comment: it's already getting the elements that contain 'Evelyn', however it's not pushing them into an array. If you want to push them over an array you'll have to use `newdata.push(args)` considering that the array's name is `newdata`